# Xming for Linux? (Aka run a display/x11 server inside a window)

Tags: ssh, fedora, gnome3, chroot, xming

With Xming I can run an X11 server inside a window and then run mate-session to get a very fast remote desktop inside a window. On Linux, I'm not entirely sure how to X11 forward mate-session to just one window.

I know how to replace my entire desktop with the tunneled desktop. I know how to do it to a TTY, I know how to do it for individual programs and I know how to do it inside a virtual machine.

It just seems strange that I wouldn't be able to do it in a minimize-able window, like you would with a remmina VNC connection.

Is there a program that provides an x11 xserver inside a window? or is there a good way to do that with a chroot? or something else similarly efficient.

I'm running Fedora 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the questions you ask is: "Is there a program that provides an x11 xserver inside a window?"

It sounds like `Xnest` might answer that question.  Xnest is "A nested X server that runs as an X application".  I know that I've used it in the past to show me unusual window managers that I had compiled from source, and didn't want to have crash my whole system.  I'm not sure it's the answer to your problem, however.

Comment: This works, but not very well for remote desktops. For some reason it becomes dog slow. I first `Xnest -ac :12 &` then `DISPLAY=:12 gnome-terminal` then tunnel `ssh -X -C hostname` and finally `mate-session`. But it becomes unusably slow after a minute or so on a 5mbps up server. X2GO is far faster with similar technology.